# error in flutter code of putting image inside flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, fluent-nhibernate, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'package:';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget
{            @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0,top: 40.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.lightGreen,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>
              [ Row(
            children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(child: Text(
                  "Spice jet",
                  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                      fontSize: 35.0,
                      fontFamily: 'railway',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      color: Colors.white),)),

   Expanded(child:Text(

                  "Spice jet",
                  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                      fontSize: 35.0,
                      fontFamily: 'railway',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      color: Colors.white),
                )

   ),
],),

                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                      "Spice jet",
                      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                          fontSize: 35.0,
                          fontFamily: 'railway',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          color: Colors.white),)),

                    Expanded(child:Text(

                      "Spice jet",
                      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                          fontSize: 35.0,
                          fontFamily: 'railway',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    )

                    ),
                  ],
                ),
futo()


],
            )));
  }}
class futo extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context)
{
  AssetImage assetImage = AssetImage('assets/images/34.png');
  Image image = Image(image: assetImage);
  return Container(child: image,);
}
}
```

the error shown is

√  Built build\host\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55447/4v1zroR_P-8=/ws
Syncing files to device Infinix X680B...
I/GED     ( 4227): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 2, oppidx_max 2, oppidx_min 0

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
Horizontal RenderFlex with multiple children has a null textDirection, so the layout order is undefined.
'package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart':
Failed assertion: line 453 pos 18: 'textDirection != null'

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

```
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Row file:///D:/helloworld/lib/main.dart:15:17
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderFlex._debugHasNecessaryDirections (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:453:18)
#3      RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:918:12)
#4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#5      ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:54:11)
#6      RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:829:43)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderFlex#8fff6 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=350.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: MISSING
...  direction: horizontal
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  verticalDirection: down
RenderObject: RenderFlex#8fff6 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=350.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: MISSING
  direction: horizontal
  mainAxisAlignment: start
  mainAxisSize: max
  crossAxisAlignment: center
  verticalDirection: down
  child 1: RenderParagraph#ccbd1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.tight
    constraints: MISSING
   size: MISSING
   textAlign: start
   textDirection: ltr
...    softWrap: wrapping at box width
...    overflow: clip
...    maxLines: unlimited
...    text: TextSpan
...      inherit: true
...      color: Color(0xffffffff)
...      family: railway
...      size: 35.0
...      weight: 700
...      decoration: TextDecoration.none
...      "Spice jet"
...  child 2: RenderParagraph#23d27 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.tight
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
...    textAlign: start
...    textDirection: ltr
...    softWrap: wrapping at box width
...    overflow: clip
...    maxLines: unlimited
...    text: TextSpan
...      inherit: true
...      color: Color(0xffffffff)
...      family: railway
...      size: 35.0
...      weight: 700
...      decoration: TextDecoration.none
...      "Spice jet"
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#8fff6 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///D:/helloworld/lib/main.dart:13:20
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1930:12)
#3      ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:55:18)
#4      RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:829:43)
#5      RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:931:32)
#6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderFlex#494fd relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=350.0, 0.0<=h<=732.0)
...  size: MISSING
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  verticalDirection: down
RenderObject: RenderFlex#494fd relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=350.0, 0.0<=h<=732.0)
  size: MISSING
  direction: vertical
  mainAxisAlignment: start
  mainAxisSize: max
  crossAxisAlignment: center
  verticalDirection: down
...  child 1: RenderFlex#8fff6 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=350.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...    size: MISSING
...    direction: horizontal
...    mainAxisAlignment: start
...    mainAxisSize: max
...    crossAxisAlignment: center
...    verticalDirection: down
...    child 1: RenderParagraph#ccbd1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.tight
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      textAlign: start
...      textDirection: ltr
...      softWrap: wrapping at box width
...      overflow: clip
...      maxLines: unlimited
...      text: TextSpan
...        inherit: true
...        color: Color(0xffffffff)
...        family: railway
...        size: 35.0
...        weight: 700
...        decoration: TextDecoration.none
...        "Spice jet"
...    child 2: RenderParagraph#23d27 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.tight
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      textAlign: start
...      textDirection: ltr
...      softWrap: wrapping at box width
...      overflow: clip
...      maxLines: unlimited
...      text: TextSpan
...        inherit: true
...        color: Color(0xffffffff)
...        family: railway
...        size: 35.0
...        weight: 700
...        decoration: TextDecoration.none
...        "Spice jet"
...  child 2: RenderFlex#3f52e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
...    direction: horizontal
...    mainAxisAlignment: start
...    mainAxisSize: max
...    crossAxisAlignment: center
...    verticalDirection: down
...    child 1: RenderParagraph#40422 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.tight
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      textAlign: start
...      textDirection: ltr
...      softWrap: wrapping at box width
...      overflow: clip
...      maxLines: unlimited
...      text: TextSpan
...        inherit: true
...        color: Color(0xffffffff)
...        family: railway
...        size: 35.0
...        weight: 700
...        decoration: TextDecoration.none
...        "Spice jet"
...    child 2: RenderParagraph#62cfe NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.tight
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      textAlign: start
...      textDirection: ltr
...      softWrap: wrapping at box width
...      overflow: clip
...      maxLines: unlimited
...      text: TextSpan
...        inherit: true
...        color: Color(0xffffffff)
...        family: railway
...        size: 35.0
...        weight: 700
...        decoration: TextDecoration.none
...        "Spice jet"
...  child 3: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#43cb8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
...    child: RenderImage#39fe6 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...      parentData: <none>
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      image: null
...      alignment: Alignment.center
...      invertColors: false
...      filterQuality: low
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 348 pos 12: 'child!.hasSize': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Container file:///D:/helloworld/lib/main.dart:9:16
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderAligningShiftedBox.alignChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:348:12)
#3      RenderPositionedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:442:7)
#4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#5      RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:233:12)
#6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderPositionedBox#6f70a relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=350.0, 0.0<=h<=732.0)
...  size: Size(350.0, 732.0)
...  alignment: Alignment.center
...  widthFactor: expand
...  heightFactor: expand
RenderObject: RenderPositionedBox#6f70a relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=350.0, 0.0<=h<=732.0)
  size: Size(350.0, 732.0)
  alignment: Alignment.center
  widthFactor: expand
  heightFactor: expand
...  child: RenderFlex#494fd relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=350.0, 0.0<=h<=732.0)
...    size: MISSING
...    direction: vertical
...    mainAxisAlignment: start
...    mainAxisSize: max
...    crossAxisAlignment: center
...    verticalDirection: down
...    child 1: RenderFlex#8fff6 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
...      constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=350.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...      size: MISSING
...      direction: horizontal
...      mainAxisAlignment: start
...      mainAxisSize: max
...      crossAxisAlignment: center
...      verticalDirection: down
...      child 1: RenderParagraph#ccbd1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.tight
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        textAlign: start
...        textDirection: ltr
...        softWrap: wrapping at box width
...        overflow: clip
...        maxLines: unlimited
...        text: TextSpan
...          inherit: true
...          color: Color(0xffffffff)
...          family: railway
...          size: 35.0
...          weight: 700
...          decoration: TextDecoration.none
...          "Spice jet"
...      child 2: RenderParagraph#23d27 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.tight
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        textAlign: start
...        textDirection: ltr
...        softWrap: wrapping at box width
...        overflow: clip
...        maxLines: unlimited
...        text: TextSpan
...          inherit: true
...          color: Color(0xffffffff)
...          family: railway
...          size: 35.0
...          weight: 700
...          decoration: TextDecoration.none
...          "Spice jet"
...    child 2: RenderFlex#3f52e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      direction: horizontal
...      mainAxisAlignment: start
...      mainAxisSize: max
...      crossAxisAlignment: center
...      verticalDirection: down
...      child 1: RenderParagraph#40422 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.tight
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        textAlign: start
...        textDirection: ltr
...        softWrap: wrapping at box width
...        overflow: clip
...        maxLines: unlimited
...        text: TextSpan
...          inherit: true
...          color: Color(0xffffffff)
...          family: railway
...          size: 35.0
...          weight: 700
...          decoration: TextDecoration.none
...          "Spice jet"
...      child 2: RenderParagraph#62cfe NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.tight
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        textAlign: start
...        textDirection: ltr
...        softWrap: wrapping at box width
...        overflow: clip
...        maxLines: unlimited
...        text: TextSpan
...          inherit: true
...          color: Color(0xffffffff)
...          family: railway
...          size: 35.0
...          weight: 700
...          decoration: TextDecoration.none
...          "Spice jet"
...    child 3: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#43cb8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      child: RenderImage#39fe6 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        image: null
...        alignment: Alignment.center
...        invertColors: false
...        filterQuality: low
```

Comment: do you have `MaterialApp()` or scaffold?

Answer (score 0):

Tayba, I think you are missing the main `structure` of `flutter App`. You need to wrap everything with `MaterialApp`, then comes `Scaffold` for every page.

on your `MyApp`, do this way.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 40.0),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.lightGreen,
```

Better way is creating another widget just for `MaterialApp`.

on `main.dart` file

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
          textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
        ),
      ),
      home: HomePage (),
      
    );
  }
}
```

then create another file `home.dart` or any name you prefer.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(),
    );
  }
}
```

while you create another screen, provide `Scaffold`. but nested widget doesnt need another `Scaffold`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **MaterialApp**  and try to update like this. (If you want, you can add **Scaffold** as well)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// import 'package:';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Center(
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 40.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              color: Colors.lightGreen,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                        "Spice jet",
                        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                            fontSize: 35.0,
                            fontFamily: 'railway',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            color: Colors.white),
                      )),
                      Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                        "Spice jet",
                        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                            fontSize: 35.0,
                            fontFamily: 'railway',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            color: Colors.white),
                      )),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                        "Spice jet",
                        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                            fontSize: 35.0,
                            fontFamily: 'railway',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            color: Colors.white),
                      )),
                      Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                        "Spice jet",
                        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                            fontSize: 35.0,
                            fontFamily: 'railway',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            color: Colors.white),
                      )),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Futo()
                ],
              ))),
    );
  }
}

class Futo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AssetImage assetImage = AssetImage('assets/images/34.png');
    Image image = Image(image: assetImage);
    return Container(
      child: image,
    );
  }
}
```