# TicTactoe using javascript minmax algorithm

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe, minmax

There's a function called "table" that creates a clickable table, where the clicked values are stored in a variable called "board".
After initializing the "board", another matrix called "a" is created with values {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}.
The "getlines" function checks all possible winning combinations in rows, columns, and diagonals.
The problem is with the "checkWinner3()", "minimax()", and "computermovedifficult()" functions. In these functions:

Every move results in a score of -Infinity.
Only the first 'O' is written on the board, and subsequent 'O's are not written.

```js
let winner = null;
           let wins = 0;
         let turn = "X";
           let board = initializeBoard(3);
           function generateTable() {
           const table = document.getElementById("board");
           table.innerHTML = "";
           // Generate rows and cells based on the matrix size
           for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                      const row = document.createElement("tr");
                      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                                 const cell = document.createElement("td");
                                 cell.setAttribute(
                                            "onclick",
                                            `cellClick(${i * 3 + j})`,
                                 );
                                 row.appendChild(cell);
                      }
                      table.appendChild(row);
           }}

         generateTable();
         function initializeBoard() {
           let board = [];
           for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
                      board.push(null);
           }
           return board;}
          console.log(board);
         let lines1 = [[]];
          function getlines(a) {
           let ijk = 3 - 2;
           for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                                 if (j < ijk) {
                                            if (
                                                       isValidIndex(a, i, j) &&
                                                       isValidIndex(
                                                                  a,
                                                                  i,
                                                                  j + 1,
                                                       ) &&
                                                       isValidIndex(a, i, j + 2)
                                            ) {
                                                       lines1.push([
                                                                  a[i][j],
                                                                  a[i][j + 1],
                                                                  a[i][j + 2],
                                                       ]);
                                            }
                                 }
                                 if (i < ijk) {
                                            if (
                                                       isValidIndex(a, i, j) &&
                                                       isValidIndex(
                                                                  a,
                                                                  i + 1,
                                                                  j,
                                                       ) &&
                                                       isValidIndex(a, i + 2, j)
                                            ) {
                                                       lines1.push([
                                                                  a[i][j],
                                                                  a[i + 1][j],
                                                                  a[i + 2][j],
                                                       ]);
                                            }
                                 }
                                 // for left diagonal
                                 if (i < ijk && j < ijk) {
                                            if (
                                                       isValidIndex(a, i, j) &&
                                                       isValidIndex(
                                                                  a,
                                                                  i + 1,
                                                                  j + 1,
                                                       ) &&
                                                       isValidIndex(
                                                                  a,
                                                                  i + 2,
                                                                  j + 2,
                                                       )
                                            ) {
                                                       lines1.push([
                                                                  a[i][j],
                                                                  a[i + 1][
                                                                             j +
                                                                                        1
                                                                  ],
                                                                  a[i + 2][
                                                                             j +
                                                                                        2
                                                                  ],
                                                       ]);
                                            }
                                 }
                                 //   for right diagonal
                                 if (i < ijk && j >= 2) {
                                            if (
                                                       isValidIndex(a, i, j) &&
                                                       isValidIndex(
                                                                  a,
                                                                  i + 1,
                                                                  j - 1,
                                                       ) &&
                                                       isValidIndex(
                                                                  a,
                                                                  i + 2,
                                                                  j - 2,
                                                       )
                                            ) {
                                                       lines1.push([
                                                                  a[i][j],
                                                                  a[i + 1][
                                                                             j -
                                                                                        1
                                                                  ],
                                                                  a[i + 2][
                                                                             j -
                                                                                        2
                                                                  ],
                                                       ]);
                                            }
                                 }
                                 lines1 = lines1.filter((arr) => arr.length > 0);
                      }
           }
           return lines1;
                  }
            function isValidIndex(array, row, col) {
           return (
                      row >= 0 &&
                      row < array.length &&
                      col >= 0 &&
                      col < array[row].length
           );
              }
          function generateMatrixWin(matrixSize) {
           let matrix = [];
           let count = 0;
           // Create the matrix
           for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                      let row = [];
                      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                                 row.push(count);
                                 count++;
                      }
                      matrix.push(row);
           }
           return matrix;
                        }
          // Test the function with a matrix size of 5
           let resultMatrix = generateMatrixWin(3);
           let a = generateMatrixWin(3);
           // Print the result matrix
         for (let i = 0; i < resultMatrix.length; i++) {
           console.log(a[i].join("\t"));
              }
            function checkWinner3() {
           lines = getlines(a);
           // Iterate through rows
           for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                      const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
                      if (
                                 board[a] &&
                                 board[a] === board[b] &&
                                 board[a] === board[c]
                      ) {
                                 console.log(board[a]);
                                 return board[a];
                      }
           }
           for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                      if (!board[i]) {
                                 return null;
                      }
           }
           return "draw";
            }
            function printBoard() {
           const table = document.getElementById("board");
           for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                      const row = Math.floor(i / 3);
                      const col = i % 3;
                      table.rows[row].cells[col].textContent = board[i];
           }
               }
               function cellClick(index) {
           if (!winner && !board[index]) {
                      board[index] = turn;
                      printBoard();
                      winner = checkWinner3();
                      if (winner) {
                                 if (winner === "draw") {
                                            document.getElementById(
                                                       "result",
                                            ).textContent =
                                                       "It's a draw! Thanks for playing.";
                                 } else {
                                            document.getElementById(
                                                       "result",
                                            ).textContent =
                                                       `Congratulations! ${winner} have won! Thanks  for playing.`;
                                 }
                      } else {
                                 turn =
                                            turn === "X"
                                                       ? computermovedifficult()
                                                       : "X";
                      }
           }
                                  }
                                //   }
                 function computermoveeasy() {
           const table = document.getElementById("board");
           do {
                      index = Math.floor(Math.random() * board.length);
           } while (board[index] !== null);
           board[index] = "O"; // Place the computer's move at the randomly generated index
           for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
                      const row = Math.floor(i / 3);
                      const col = i % 3;
                      table.rows[row].cells[col].textContent = board[i];
           }
           turn = "X";
           lines = getlines(a);
           // Iterate through rows
           for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                      const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
                      if (
                                 board[a] &&
                                 board[a] === board[b] &&
                                 board[a] === board[c]
                      ) {
                                 console.log("WINS" + board[a]);
                            document.getElementById("result").textContent =
                                 `Congratulations! ${board[a]} have won! Thanks for                      playing.`;
                                 return board[a];
                      }
           }
                 }
          function computermovedifficult() {
           let bestScore = -Infinity;
           let bestMove = null;
           const table = document.getElementById("board");
           for (let index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
                      //   if (board[index] === null) {
                      if (
                                 board[index] === null ||
                                 board[index] === undefined ||
                                 board[index] === ""
                      ) {
                                 board[index] = "O";
                                 let score = minimax(board, 0, false);
                                 board[index] = ""; // Undo the move
                                 console.log(`Move: ${index}, Score: ${score}`);
                                 if (score > bestScore) {
                                            bestScore = score;
                                            bestMove = index;
                                 }
                      }
           }
           board[bestMove] = "O"; // Update the board with the best move
           console.log("Best Move:", bestMove); // Log the best move for debugging
           console.log("Best Score:", bestScore); // Log the best score for debugging
           console.log("Updated Board:", board); // Log the updated board array for debugging
           turn = "X";
           return turn;
             }
        function minimax(board, depth, isMaximizing) {
           lines = getlines(a);
           // Iterate through rows
           for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                      const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
                      for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                                 if (!board[i]) {
                                            result = null;
                                 }
                      }
                      result = "draw";
                      if (
                                 board[a] &&
                                 board[a] === board[b] &&
                                 board[a] === board[c]
                      ) {
                                 console.log(board[a]);
                                 result = board[a];
                      }
           }
           if (result !== null) {
                      // Adjust scores based on the result
                      if (result === "draw") {
                                 console.log("draw");
                                 return 0;
                      } else if (result === "O") {
                                 return 10 - depth;
                      } else if (result === "X") {
                                 return depth - 10;
                      }
           }
           if (depth >= 5) {
                      return 0; // Return 0 when reaching the maximum depth
           }
           if (isMaximizing) {
                      let bestScore = -Infinity;
                      for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                                 if (board[i] === "") {
                                            board[i] = "O";
                                            let score = minimax(
                                                       board,
                                                       depth + 1,
                                                       false,
                                            );
                                            board[i] = null;
                                            bestScore = Math.max(
                                                       score,
                                                       bestScore,
                                            );
                                            turn = "X";
                                 }
                      }
                      return bestScore;
           } else {
                      let bestScore = Infinity;
                      for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                                 //  ===''
                                 if (board[i] === "") {
                                            board[i] = "X";
                                            let score = minimax(
                                                       board,
                                                       depth + 1,
                                                       true,
                                            );
                                            board[i] = null;
                                            bestScore = Math.min(
                                                       score,
                                                       bestScore,
                                            );
                                            turn = "O";
                                 }
                      }
                      return bestScore;
           }
                 }
```

```css
body, html {  height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction:column; }
        table {  border-collapse: collapse; }
        td {    border: 1px solid black;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 20px; }

    
        .result {
            margin-top: 50px;
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.4.2/d3.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
     </head>

      <body>
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1> <br>
    <table id="board"> </table>
    <div id="result" class="result"></div>
       </body>
```

```
        <!-- language: css -->    
 
     .result {
         margin-top: 50px;
       font-size: 1.5em;
         }


      <!-- end snippet -->

      <!-- language: html -->     
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.4.2/d3.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
     </head>

      <body>
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1> <br>
    <table id="board"> </table>
    <div id="result" class="result"></div>
       </body>



      <!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: You asked a question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68612165/5459839) and didn't gave any feedback to those that answered. Were neither answers of use to you?

Comment: Your `minimax()` function is checking for `"tie"` - but you use `"draw"` everywhere else. Use constants to prevent issues like this. As a side note, your `turn = turn === "X" ? ...` line uses `computermovedifficult()` as its `true` result but that function doesn't return a value - leaving `turn` as `undefined` / `null`.

Comment: helo i added return turn;  in "computermovedifficult()" function and added draw condition in minmax still problem persists this "computermovedifficult()" function traverses linearly and Puts O row wise in blanks it doesnot apply minmax() function

Comment: Have you changed `if (result === "tie") {` to `if (result === "draw") {`? When I changed that, the `bestScore` started working properly and therefore it put an 'O' in each time.

Comment: yes i changed it it works good the previous error is not happening ,but another error function is never called  minmax logic

Comment: Ah, OK, I understand. It _should_ be called... as soon as the computer finds an empty square. At this point I would strongly recommend trying to trace (debug) your code using Chrome's Developer Tools or similar debugging tools. At a push, you can put out lots of console logs to show what values you are getting around that area to try to discover why it is not getting to that point.  We can't really debug it for you :)